# How can I make my Elastic Beanstalk website route HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up my SSL certificate on my Elastic Beanstalk node website, but my HTTP routes aren't working properly.

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html) to set up my load balancer for my EB, and it looks like the below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKL8v.png

However I want it to go to HTTPS whenever I go to www.mywebsitecom, mywebsite.com.

At the moment it only goes to HTTPS if I manually type in https:// at the beginning of the URL, and only when I do https://www.mywebsite.com. It doesn't work at https://mywebsite.com.

Otherwise all traffic goes to unsecured HTTP on www.mywebsite.com (without typing the https).

I have set up the certificate properly I believe, and set the DNS A record in Route 53. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using an Application Load Balancer, you can configure it to redirect HTTP to HTTPS by following this answer https://serverfault.com/a/939013/32351 If you are using a Classic Load Balancer you will need to configure the web server software running on your Elastic Beanstalk server to perform the redirect.

Comment: What stack are you using?  You can also force https at the application layer.  For example, in Ruby on Rails, you can set your production configuration file to force ssl for all requests.

Comment: I am using nodejs. I think I can change the settings through nginx. Do you know if I can change the load balancer to an Application Load Balancer from a CLB and do it all from the AWS interface?

Answer (score 0):

To change your CLB to ALB, refer the link: [Migrating from CLB to ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/migrate-to-application-load-balancer.html)

Once that is done, make sure that you update your new ALB’s DNS name in your **Route 53's Alias Target Field.**
If everything is working fine, then you can delete your CLB.